# WordPress Books Gallery plugin only allow administrator to add

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I installed WordPress and added the WordPress Books Gallery, it allows the user to add books and display them . it works very good and has all i need,  find it better than other plugins.

the problem is that it only allows the users of the role administrator to add books, it doesn't allow any other role.

I searched for a solution but i didn't find anything that can help. Even the description of the Pro features doesn't include the solution for the problem. How can i fix this problem?